# Ffmpeg output not working

Tags: interface, screencast

I was trying to make a screencast but as soon as I start recording, the "Capture" button that you press to stop recording goes away and the recording stops. I have output set to MP4 in H.264 but when I set it to AVI or an image sequence, it works fine.

I guess I could switch it to one of those, but that really wouldn't be the best option for me.